# How to store Form Data (a Django form) to browser's local storage, using javascript and not Django sessions?

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-templates, local-storage

I want to take the data from the user through a form (a Django form) and store it  in the browser's local storage, using javascript and without using Django sessions.

My code looks like:

./forms.py :

```
class digitize(forms.Form):

    medicinename = forms.CharField(label='Medicinename', max_length=100)
    quantity = forms.CharField(label='Quantity', max_length=100)
```

./e_commerce.html :

```
<form id="digitizer_form" role="form" action="/MediciansDigitizer/Presc/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   {% csrf_token %}

   <h3 class="prod_title">Add Detail</h3>

   {{iform.as_table}}{{ dform.as_p }}

   <div class="">
   <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Digitize</button>
   </div>

</form> 

<script>

        window.onload = function() {

        // Check for LocalStorage support.
        if (localStorage) {

            // Add an event listener for form submissions
            document.getElementById('digitizer_form').addEventListener('submit', function() {

            // Get the value of the MedicineName field :

Now, this is where I need help. Here I want to give in the 'MedicineName' 
field of the form defined above, So that
I can get the MedicineName entered by the user from the form
and store it in the browser storage. 
The logic should look something like this:

            // get the value of the MedicineName so that
               I can store it in a variable like this:

             var Medicine = document.getElementById('MedicineName').value; 

//but because I am using a django form, and linking it 
  in the e_commerce.html template through {%csrf_token%} ,
  {{iform.as_table}} and {{ dform.as_p }} 
  and have not assigned any id ('MedicineName') to any element (as 
  I didn't create any form element manually inside the html template, 
but has made a "form class" in forms.py), I can't follow
  this approach and so I am stuck here because I don't know how to 
  do it the other way round.

            // and then Save the variable in localStorage
              like this :
            localStorage.setItem('Medicine', MedicineName);
            });

          }

        }
</script>
```

So, how to use the MedicineName entered by the user from the Django form inside the javascript in the html template, to store the name in my browser's local storage through javascript?

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just an aside: wouldn't `if (localStorage)` give a reference error if it isn't defined? As compared to `if (window.localStorage)`...

Comment: @nnnnnn okay, so how should I define it then? I mean what's the way that it should be included so I can use localStorage?

Comment: this doesn't really have anything at all to do with django does it?

Comment: I used the term Django to indicate that the form has been made from the django form class. So basically I don't know how to use the variables of a django form in <script> tags inside my html template @e4c5

Comment: Please explain what exactly you mean by variables of a django form. When a django form is rendered it becomes plain old HTML accessible via javascript just like any other html component

Comment: yes I am looking for the same thing. By Django variable I mean the name of a particular field in the Django form class. If the MedicineName is the field of a form class, then the corresponding form input (converted to an <input> tag) will be obtained, having value = "MedicineName", in which any charfield will be entered by the user. Now I want to access this passed value using: `document.getElementById('Some id name for this <input> tag').value`. But because I created it using form class, this <input> tag doesn't have any id associated with it. So how can I access this value now? @e4c5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your form rendering

```
<form id="digitizer_form" role="form" action="/MediciansDigitizer/Presc/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   {% csrf_token %}

   <h3 class="prod_title">Add Detail</h3>

   {{iform.as_table}}

   <div class="">
   <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Digitize</button>
   </div>

</form> 

<form id="other_form" role="form" method="post" >

   {{ dform.as_p }}

   <div class="">
   <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Digitize</button>
   </div>

</form>
```

These are two forms so they should be rendered as two different forms. Else you will find that server side form validation does not work. If you need one HTML form with fields from two django forms, have one django form extend the other.

Then since you have a form element named `medicinename` rendering the form will result in an HTML input element with an id of `id_medicinename` thus you can access it as

```
 document.getElementById('id_medicinename').value
```

Comment: thanks a tonne for the answer. this is exactly what I was looking for. I'll test it and see if it works, and so will accept your answer soon. :)

Comment: Great, let me know how it goes

Comment: Oh! since you have accepted, I think it has worked :-) all the best for your project